# How to characterize the class of $(\mathfrak{g},K)$-modules with a fixed lowest K-type in the framework of D-modules?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, flag-varieties, geometric-representation-theory

Let $G$ be a real semisimple Lie group, $K$ be a maximal compact subgroup. Let $\mathfrak{g}_0$ and $\mathfrak{k}_0$ be their real Lie algebras respectively. Let $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{k}$ be their complexifications. We have the standard notation of $(\mathfrak{g},K)$-modules. Moreover the category of $(\mathfrak{g},K)$-modules with a fixed infinitesimal character is equivalent to the category of corresponding twisted D-modules on the falg variety of $\mathfrak{g}$.

Let $\pi$ be a $(\mathfrak{g},K)$-module. We call $\mu\in \hat{K}$ a $K$-type of $\pi$ if $\mu$ occurs in $\pi|_K$, and $\mu$ is called a $\textit{lowest}$ $K$-type of $\pi$ if $\parallel \mu \parallel $ is minimal among all $K$-types of $\pi$.

Now let $G$ itself be a $\textit{complex}$ semisimple group. In this case $\mathfrak{g}\cong \mathfrak{g}_0\oplus \mathfrak{g}_0$ as complex Lie algebras. Moreover it can be proved that the lowest $K$-type of an irreducible $(\mathfrak{g},K)$-module is unique.

My question is: First, what is the relation between the lowest $K$-type and the infinitesimal character of a $(\mathfrak{g},K)$-module? Second, how to characterize the $(\mathfrak{g},K)$-modules with a fixed lowest $K$ type in the framework of D-modules?